# Any problems in installing ROS on Windows 10 using Virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04, ros, robotics

Is it a good practice to install ROS (Robot Operating System ) on Windows 10 using a virtual machine ? Are there any limitations that I would face doing so ?.

I know its a basic and simple question. But as a beginner I think I must get help on here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as ROS **itself** is concerned, running it in a Linux VM should be fine. Depending on your usage you may run into trouble brought by software used alongside ROS.

[Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/) for example will likely run very slowly if at all on a VM (though it's true this again depends on hardware). I was unable to get it to run properly on an Ubuntu VM so I just started using Ubuntu as the host OS.

Try dual booting Windows and Ubuntu if you cannot drop Windows entirely.